# Не работает класс?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не работает класс. Хочу вывести информацию о цвете

```
class Vehicle(object):
"""docstring"""

def __init__(self, color, size, price, sale, country, year, brand, material, gender, sport):
    """Constructor"""
    self.color = color
    self.size = size
    self.price = price
    self.sale = sale
    self.price = price
    self.country = country
    self.year = year
    self.brand = brand
    self.material = material
    self.gender = gender
    self.sport = sport



def display_info(self):
    print("Color ", self.color)
```

person1 = Vehicle("red")
person1.display_info()

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он не работает?

Comment: не поверите у себя на компе запустил, не работает (((

Comment: Что такое «не работает» и чем это отличается от «работает»?

Comment: Код работает с ошыбкой!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: С какой ошыбкой?

Answer (score 2):

У вас на самом то деле ошибка очень простая. Дело в том что, при попытке запустить данный код у вас будет следующая ошибка:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 9 required positional arguments: 'size', 'price', 'sale', 'country', 'year', 'brand', 'material', 'gender', and 'sport'

Если вы не поняли что там написано, возможно не знание языка, то в данном сообщение пишется что метод `init` должен еще получить 9 **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫХ** аргумента, ну и затем идет перечисление каких именно аргументов у вас не хватает.

Ну и чтобы избежать этого можем назначить этим аргументам значения по умолчанию:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    """Class docstring"""

    def __init__(self, color=None, size=None, price=None, sale=None, country=None, year=None, brand=None, material=None, gender=None, sport=None):
        """Method docstring (Constructor)"""
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.price = price
        self.sale = sale
        self.country = country
        self.year = year
        self.brand = brand
        self.material = material
        self.gender = gender
        self.sport = sport
```

Ну и после этих простых изменений наш метод(конструктор) `init` запуститься, и все будет работать:

```
vehicle1 = Vehicle('Red')
vehicle1.display_info()
# output: Red
vehicle2 = Vehicle()
vehicle2.display_info()
# output: None
```